# Could Magneto control Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Whether in comics, films, or a new animated tv series, Magneto has always been shown to be exceptionally powerful, whether or not it's lifting a submarine or ripping Adamantium from bone. However, I have always wondered: could Magneto control Wolverine? I know that, on several occasions, he has been known to halt or throw Wolverine, but I have never seen him take control of the berserker X-Man, even though Wolverine's entire skeletal structure is coated in the indestructible metal. What I want to know is why. Surely somebody would have some advice. NOTE: Any information from any continuity is acceptable

Comment: Do you mean simply to control Wolverine's whole body in the way Magneto controls his claws? Or do you mean control as in "animate convincingly", e.g. to make him move around and walk like a natural person?

Comment: Yes. In the X-men films, Magneto controls wolverine's upper body on several occasions.

Comment: Also in the comics he tosses Logan around like a doll often and in the 1990's he ripped all of his Adamantium from Wolvie's body.

Answer (score 3):

Magneto is not a typically savage or psychopathic or sociopathic villain. He rarely employs subversive techniques like brain washing or manipulating others to fight amongst themselves through mind control, drugs, or hallucinations. He doesn't get his jollies from that. He is not sadistic like that (at least towards mutants).

Using Wolverine as a meat puppet has no benefit to Magneto. Other villains like Sinister or Apocalypse would and have jumped at the chance though.

Of course Magneto will push and move Wolverine around if there is a serious need for it,  mainly to get him out of his way though.